# Proving common law marriage, but common law spouse won't accompany me on the trip

Tags: visas, canada, nigerian-citizens, proof-of-ties

I have submitted my visa application for Canada. Now I've just been going through most of the documents I made available, Business names + affidavits (I used my father's business in this case as I happen to be his only son and all that) Now the one which shocked me is about common law relationships.

I would only be away for a couple of days, I read on here https://www.ackahlaw.com/news/top-10-mistakes-that-will-sink-your-canada-immigration-application I would need to make provision for common law marriages, but both on the form and online I didn't see something like that. Since she is not accompanying me on this short trip, would there have been a need to include any formal documentation? Just to know and be certain in this case. Hope I did not make any form of mistake here. Asides that, other documents including hotel reservation, proof of business, payslips and employment letter  etc. I made readily available.

Hope I didn't make any mistakes this time.

Answer (score 5):

The article you linked to is about permanent residence in Canada, as you are just applying for a visitor visa for a short time this doesn't apply to you.